# Subtract datetime in Django - no output

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I want to get the "age" of a user account in my Django app. This is what I did:

```
class UserData(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,unique=True)
    birth = models.IntegerField(default=1900)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)

    @property
    def isNew(self):
        if (datetime.datetime.now()-self.user.date_joined) < datetime.timedelta(days=40):
            return True;
        else:
            return False;
```

In my template there is a different view depending on the output of this function. But there is basically NO output.

When simply "printing" the output there is simply nothing returned. When returning the "datetime" and the "date_joined" the date is shown. When returning str(type()) of both "datetime.datetime" is returned. But when returning the difference (or the type of the difference) there is absolutely NOTHING returned. When doing the same in my python console there is a timedelta returned - exactly what I expect.

Any idea where to search next? I can't figure out what's happening to completely prevent this function from giving any output without crashing the app.

Comment: Could you show us your model ?

Comment: I added the complete model right now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to substract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes.

You need to install pytz `pip install pytz` and change your method with the following:

```
import datetime, pytz

@property
def isNew(self):
    return pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.now())-self.user.date_joined < datetime.timedelta(days=40)
```

Comment: That solved the issue - thanks a lot. How comes that there are different types of datetimes used in this context?

Comment: You have offset aware and offset naive datetime. When you use datetime.datetime.now() your application doesn't know which timezone to use. More info here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
@property
def isNew(self):
    return (
        datetime.datetime.now() - self.user.date_joined < 
        datetime.timedelta(days=40)
    )
```

Problem in your code was

```
return False
```

as first line of your property so it always returned false.

Moreover you should not use semicolon in python

Comment: Just added that for testing and forgot to remove it in my post - sorry